# Объединить два массива в один по ключам

Tags: php

```
Array(

[0] => Array
    (
        [orders] => 5
        [manager_customer_id] => 85
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [orders] => 1
        [manager_customer_id] => 124
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [orders] => 6
        [manager_customer_id] => 86
    )
 )

Array(


[0] => Array
    (
        [name_manager_customer] => Nick Name
        [manager_customer_id] => 85
        [manager_id] => 699
        [city_manager_customer] => 
        [shop_manager_customer] => 
        [phone_manager_customer] => 
        [vk_id_manager_customer] => just_nick_name
        [card_number] => 
        [card_name] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name_manager_customer] => Queen Time
        [manager_customer_id] => 124
        [manager_id] => 699
        [city_manager_customer] => 
        [shop_manager_customer] => 
        [phone_manager_customer] => 
        [vk_id_manager_customer] => 
        [card_number] => 
        [card_name] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name_manager_customer] => БигБен
        [manager_customer_id] => 86
        [manager_id] => 699
        [city_manager_customer] => 
        [shop_manager_customer] => 
        [phone_manager_customer] => 
        [vk_id_manager_customer] => 
        [card_number] => 
        [card_name] => 
    )
)
```

У них `manager_customer_id` одинаковые ни как не могу сообразить как объединить,
что бы получилось

```
Array(


 [0] => Array
   (
       [name_manager_customer] => Nick Name
       [manager_customer_id] => 85
       [manager_id] => 699
       [city_manager_customer] => 
       [shop_manager_customer] => 
       [phone_manager_customer] => 
       [vk_id_manager_customer] => just_nick_name
       [card_number] => 
       [card_name] => 
       [orders] => 5 
    )
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

Ещё вариант:

```
<?php

$a_1 = array(
    array(
        'orders' => 5,
        'manager_customer_id' => 85
    ),

    array(
        'orders' => 1,
        'manager_customer_id' => 124
    ),

    array(
        'orders' => 6,
        'manager_customer_id' => 86
    )
);

$a_2 = array(

    array(
        'name_manager_customer' => 'Nick Name',
        'manager_customer_id' => 85,
        'manager_id' => 699,
        'city_manager_customer' => '',
        'shop_manager_customer' => '',
        'phone_manager_customer' => '',
        'vk_id_manager_customer' => 'just_nick_name',
        'card_number' => '',
        'card_name' => ''
    ),

    array(
        'name_manager_customer' => 'Queen Time',
        'manager_customer_id' => 124,
        'manager_id' => 699,
        'city_manager_customer' => '',
        'shop_manager_customer' => '',
        'phone_manager_customer' => '',
        'vk_id_manager_customer' => '',
        'card_number' => '',
        'card_name' => ''
    ),

    array(
        'name_manager_customer' => '',
        'manager_customer_id' => 86,
        'manager_id' => 699,
        'city_manager_customer' => '',
        'shop_manager_customer' => '',
        'phone_manager_customer' => '',
        'vk_id_manager_customer' => '',
        'card_number' => '',
        'card_name' => ''
    )
);


$result = [];

for ($i = 0, $all = count($a_1); $i < $all; $i++) {
    $result[] = array_merge($a_2[$i], $a_1[$i]);
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: дак там вопрос то в том, что складывать не парами надо, а по совпадающим идентификаторам, и порядок следования может быть различен. иначе вообще не понятно, в чем проблема была

Comment: Так не правильно количество `orders` показывает  не совподает

Comment: @Sender1050 вроде бы всё правильно:  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c1331d384edcafb27734fd79b971b3ea86165c14 Или я не так понял?

Comment: @Эдуард так если отдельно взять протестировать то все нормально, а в коде почему то не те данные выдает, ну может я что то не так сделал.

Comment: @Sender1050 ну, если отдельно работает, но не работает в вашем коде, то либо вы не верно указали исходные данные в первом посту, либо допускаете ошибку в своём варианте.

Comment: @Эдуард исходные данные правильные это у меня в коде ошибка при выводе

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите ваши исходные данные

```
$orders = [
        ['orders' => 5, 'manager_customer_id' => 85],
        ['orders' => 1, 'manager_customer_id' => 124],
        ['orders' => 6, 'manager_customer_id' => 86]
     ];

$data = [
    [
        'name_manager_customer' => "Nick Name",
        'manager_customer_id' => 85,
        'manager_id' => 699,
    ],
    [
        'name_manager_customer' => "Queen Time",
        'manager_customer_id' => 124,
        'manager_id' => 699,
    ],
    [
        'name_manager_customer' => "БигБен",
        'manager_customer_id' => 86,
        'manager_id' => 699,
    ]
];
```

и преобразуйте первый массив к удобному виду, где идентификаторы будут ключами

```
$odata =  array_column($orders, 'orders', 'manager_customer_id');
```

пройдитесь по второму массиву, и расставьте значения

```
foreach($data as &$d){
    $d['orders'] =  $odata[$d['manager_customer_id']];
}
```

Если второй массив трогать не надо, то сложите результат в третий

```
$result = [];
foreach($data as $d){
    $d['orders'] = $odata[$d['manager_customer_id']];
    $result[] = $d;
}
```